# How to right shift the values using arm neon instruction

Tags: simd

i have read about how to left shift values.How to right sift values using SIMD neon instructions? there is no command as such provided for it.Can i negate the values and left shift? if so how do i negate them?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. It may mean you want to right shift the elements of a vector or you want to right shift the bits inside the elements. Since in the end you wonder how to deny the values​​, I assume you mean right shift the bits of the elements. I wait a clarification before posting a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To right-shift bit-wise each element using neon, u need to negate the shift value. 
I guess 'vneg' can do the negation for you if your shift value is already in neon reg.
else you can negate the value in the arm regs before loading them to neon.